# Commercially available sprung tyres/wheels?

Tags: tire

I was wondering if anyone knew of any commercially available sprung tyres or wheels. I'm talking about wheels that take do the shock absorption instead of a pneumatic tyre.

[This is all I can find at the moment](http://www.fastcodesign.com/1665045/soft-ride-bike-has-steel-tires-and-you-can-ride-it-now:)

[image]

I'm sure I saw a kickstarter for a set a while ago but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Loopwheels](http://www.loopwheels.com/) makes bicycle wheels with springs in stead of spokes. They also had a [successful Kickstarter](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1205277475/loopwheels-for-a-smoother-more-comfortable-bicycle), so it might be what you were thinking about. They do however still rely on normal tyres and rims, so can't be said to work without pneumatic tyres. Although I bet you can run a pretty high tyre preassure quite comfortably with these wheels.

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, sadly looking at it I now remember why I didn't back it. The price and the fact that it's only for foldable bikes, although mostly the price.

Comment: I do agree that the price doesn't quite match the performance. You could use it for any bike that uses 20" wheels of course, but most of them are folding. I think this design probably wouldn't work very well for 26" or 700c wheels as the springs would have to be quite large and would probably have very bad torsion stiffness.